# Using authentication with DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Tags: mongodb, authentication, symfony

I'm currently working on a project where I use mongodb as database, and I began with no security in my mongo configuration of the symfony config.yml.

This is what my config.yml looked like since the beginning of the project.

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: mongodb://localhost:27017
        options: {}
default_database: louisv
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

With this parameters the project works very well.

But I want to add security to mongodb database. So I tried to follow documentation on mongodb to create users. I created an "admin" user for the admin database, and a "louisv" user for the louisv database (the admin database is the database existing by default, and louisv is mine).

Now I want to Symfony to use this new user. I changed my the option parameters from my conf.yml file and now this is what I have :

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: mongodb://localhost:27017
        options:
            username: louisv
            password: password
default_database: louisv
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

Now when I try to enter my application in Symfony

> Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'admin' with username 'louisv': auth fails

Which is weird cause my default_database is "louisv' and not 'admin'.

And if I change the credentials to admin's ones, I have another error:

> localhost:27017: not authorized for query on louisv.User

Which seems quite good as it seems to search for users, but I can't do queries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of:

```
server: mongodb://localhost:27017
```

The following should do the trick:

```
server: mongodb://localhost:27017/louisv
```

Apparently, the Doctrine ODM bundle also has a "db" option now, so you now have the following options:

```
connections:
    default:
        server: mongodb://louisv:password@localhost:27017/louisv
```

or

```
connections:
    default:
        server: mongodb://localhost:27017
        options:
            username: louisv
            password: password
            db: louisv
```

The first option is preferred, as it allows for automatic re-authentication in case a connection drops.

See also:

- https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/154

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now ! I searched a lot but didn't find out this simple answer ! Thx again !

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution but it is not connecting to DB. Is there any mongo restart needed after changing the DB credentials? As before there was no username and password for it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @derick's answer, my configuration was still trying to connect to the "default" database - adding the `default_database` entry solved this.

```yaml
connections:
    default:
        server: "mongodb://myuser:password@mydbserver:27017/mydb"
default_database: mydb
```

*Remember to keep usernames and passwords in a "parameters" file separate from the config file if stored in source control :)*